# java lambda expression in sorting. diff between .sort() and Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, lambda

Please see the code below, on the fourth line, put the lambda expression in the .sort() method, it works fine.

The fifth line, using Arrays.sort() will report an error.
I would like to know where is the difference between the two. and how to properly use lambda expressions in Arrays.sort()

```
    var strs = new ArrayList<String>();
    strs.add("AA");
    strs.add("BB");
    strs.sort((a,b) -> b.compareTo(a)); // OK
    // Arrays.sort(strs, (a, b) ->  b.compareTo(a) ); // CAN NOT COMPILE java: no suitable method found for sort...
```

Related questions:
[using Arrays.sort with Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878909/using-arrays-sort-with-lambda)

Comment: The first parameter of `Arrays.sort` must be an array, you passed a `List`.

Comment: you cant use utility class `Arrays` with collections. Probably you need this instead`Collections.sort(strs, (a, b) ->  b.compareTo(a));`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and lists are different so you can't pass an instance of one to a method expecting the other.  But the `List` interface has a `sort()` method that takes a `Comparator`. To sort a list,
try it like this. Strings implement the `Comparable` interface and their natural order is ascending. So just specify a reverse order `Comparator` for comparing.

```
var strs = new ArrayList<String>();
   strs.add("AA");
   strs.add("BB");

strs.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

strs.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
BB
AA
```

Answer (score 0):

As duncg mentioned just do:

```
Object[] array = strs.toArray();
Arrays.sort(array, (a, b) ->  ((String) b).compareTo((String)a) );
```